# Binding a popup to a control

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a LeafletJS control that renders a button. I want the button, when clicked, to open a popup on its position. So far I've tried calling the .bindPopup method on the control itself, which WebStorm seems to approve of, but the browser tells me that this method doesn't exist. What would be the preferred way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaflet controls don't implement the `.bindPopup` function.

Instead, you might find some luck looking at how the layers control works, it collapses/expands based on mouse events. You could potentially do something similar with your control, and show/hide your popup based on the click event and toggling a `display: none` css property.

Comment: Thanks. I opted to use a custom control that creates a Bootstrap dropdown instead, it seems to work out fine for my purposes.